# Read the content of an Excel file on the server side

Tags: c#, server, vsto, windows-server-2008, saas

I want to implement a SaaS. The software takes an Excel file, reads its content, analyse the information, and generate a useful text report. As a SaaS, users will be able to upload their Excel file via my website, and receive the text report generated by the software hosted in the server.

If the software was on Desktop, it could be coded in `C#` and `VSTO`; from an excel file, the software could launch Excel, open the file, read the content, close Excel, does the analysis, etc. However, I don't know how this can be realised **on the server side**. For instance, **how Excel could be launched on the server side?**

I guess there are two possible scenarios:

1) make the software such that it could read the content (eg, cell values, cell formulas, even VBA macros) of an Excel file, **without** launching Excel. Does anyone know if it is possible by `C#` and `VSTO`?

2) the software could launch Excel (and close it) on the server. Does anyone know which kind of server permits of that?

Comment: What's wrong with my question?

Comment: There are tons of questions for both of options you have - in current state post demonstrate *limited* amount of research on the subject which may cause downvotes. Post also potentially asks for software recommendations which is good reason to get close votes. You may want to spend a bit more time on researching existing posts on the topic and [edit] post later.

Comment: Well, i don't see there are tons of questions and especially solutions for my options in my context, though i am still searching... Anyway, I would hope people who down vote or close vote could leave a comment...

Comment: It is generally considered dangerous to downvote and comment (as plenty  people will start revenge of some sort), also if default tooltip on downvote button matches the reason there is no point of copy-paste it to comment... Anyway here is advertisement for you: company I work for builds search engine for just such cases - try it out https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+asp.net+read+excel

Comment: Thanks for that... I will look into these threads carefully... One thing is I want to retrieve cell formulas + VBA macros from a closed workbook. I am not sure if it is possible by OleDb or ADODB...

Comment: You might want to try ClosedXML.

Comment: Do you think ClosedXML can read formulas + VBA macros from a closed workbook?

Comment: I've used it to read closed workbooks.  You can find more info [here](https://closedxml.codeplex.com/documentation).  Also, you might want to check the SO [closedxml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/closedxml) tag.

Comment: There's also the [Open XML SDK](https://www.nuget.org/packages/OpenXMLSDK-MOT/).